# Login command fails and closes connection

Tags: linux, login

I’m trying to execute the `login` command but it fails.

As root (via SSH) I get:

```
root@server:~# login
Connection to 192.168.0.50 closed.
```

The SSH connection is closed. In a “physical” TTY the session is closed and I go back to the login screen.

As a regular user using sudo:

```
bilbax@server:~$ sudo login
Password: 

[1]+  Stopped                 sudo login
```

Just before this bug appeared, I tried to use the `login` command as usual, it worked, it asked for the password. I typed it wrong, I retried, but the command froze. I tried ^C, without success. So, as root, I executed `killall login`; didn't worked too. I rebooted the system and now I have to bug described above.

Did I do something wrong by killing the command?

I’m on Arch Linux x86_64 (kernel 3.4.7-1-ARCH).

Comment: You shouldn't need to run `login` at all. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I need to launch my Minecraft server under the `minecraft` account. I can’t use `su minecraft`, it causes problems with `screen` which can’t start. So I logged into `minecraft` use using `login` as root, and start the server.

Comment: @KévinLesénéchal `su` is the proper way to do what you want, not `login`. If you're having a problem getting screen to work with `su`, you should open question on that instead.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with `su` will be that it doesn't chown the tty to the new user. That doesn't matter when you're su'ing to root, but for other users not owning the tty leads to difficulty.

Running `login` from the shell used to be a normal (or at least acceptable) thing to do. Shells treated it specially, implicitly doing an `exec`. Modern shells don't seem to do that any more. Running `exec login` explicitly might help. Adding `-f username` is another thing to try.

When you do it as a non-root user, it only works if `login` is setuid-root, which used to be the standard setup but isn't so common anymore. The `sudo` version might also work if preceded by `exec`, assuming sudo is smart enough to get out of the way (i.e. do a direct exec itself, not a fork+exec+wait)

After going through all that I wonder why you don't just `ssh host -l minecraft` and cut out the middleman